# How to access variable of one class from other class?

Tags: php, zend-framework, class, object

I have situation like this:

```
// Object Class
class Person_Object {

   protected $_id;

   public function __construct( $id = null ) {
      $this->_id = $id;
   }

   public function getMapper() {
        $mapper = new Person_Mapper();
        return $mapper;
   }

   public function printIdInMapper() {
       $this->getMapper()->printIdInMapper();
   }

}

// Mapper Class
class Person_Mapper {

    public function printIdInMapper() {
       // How to access Person_Object's id here and echo id?
   }
}


// Code
$personModel = new Person_Object(10);
$personModel->printIdInMapper(); // should print 10
```

Now how to echo `Person_Object's id value 10` in `printIdInMapper()` function here

Comment: Create getter for `$_id` and pass `$this` to `printIdInMapper` I guess.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing a protected member variable outside a class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475601/accessing-a-protected-member-variable-outside-a-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Object Class
class Person_Object {

   protected $_id;

   public function __construct( $id = null ) {
      $this->_id = $id;
   }

   public function getId() {
        return $this->_id;
   }

   public function getMapper() {
        $mapper = new Person_Mapper($this);
        return $mapper;
   }

   public function printIdInMapper() {
       $this->getMapper()->printIdInMapper();
   }

}

// Mapper Class
class Person_Mapper {
    $_person

    public function __construct( $person ) {
       $this->_person = $person
    }

    public function printIdInMapper() {
       echo $this->_person->getId();
   }
}
```

Comment: OK. Creating `getId()` function in `Person_Object` is acceptable but I can't change the signature of `printIdInMapper()` function.

Comment: Can you add new functions to Person_Mapper?

Comment: yes. There is no restriction to create new functions but I can't change existing functions.

Comment: yes. It looks better. Let me try this logic in my actual code.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach:

```
class Person_Object {

   protected $_id;

   public function __construct( $id = null ) {
      $this->_id = $id;
   }

   public function getId() {
       return $this->_id;
   }

   public function getMapper() {
        $mapper = new Person_Mapper();

        $mapper->setPerson($this);

        return $mapper;
   }

   public function printIdInMapper() {
       $this->getMapper()->printIdInMapper();
   }

}

// Mapper Class
class Person_Mapper {

    protected $person;

    public function setPerson(Person_Object $person) {
        $this->person = $person;
    }

    public function getPerson() {
        return $this->person;
    }

    public function printIdInMapper() {
       echo $this->getPerson()->getId();
   }
}
```